# PDO mysqli default socket - что это такое?

Tags: php, pdo

```
mysqli::__construct ([ string $host = ini_get("mysqli.default_host") [, string  $username = ini_get("mysqli.default_user") [, string $passwd = ini_get("mysqli.default_pw") [, string $dbname = "" [, int $port = ini_get("mysqli.default_port") [, string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket") ]]]]]] )
```

что означает вот это ?:

```
 string $socket = ini_get("mysqli.default_socket")
```

Что именно такое socket ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файловый сокет. Это термин из Unix-подобных систем (пайп для Windows). Если очень кратко, то соединение происходит не через сетевое оборудование, а через файловую систему. В таком случае возможно только локальное подключение.

Comment: а для чего оно тогда нужно ? и обязательный этот атрибут ?

Comment: Во избежание недоразумений уточню, что «через файловую систему» происходит *только* соединение, а сами данные передаются по-нормальному не через ФС)

Comment: понятно , спасибо

Comment: @andreymal, что в вашем понимании "по-нормальному"? Сетевые интерфейсы не используются. Используются интерфейсы фаловой системы.

Comment: @NikolaTesla по-нормальному — это через оперативную память («буферы памяти ядра» © [википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сокет_домена_UNIX)), а не через жёсткий диск, как могут ошибочно подумать те, кто прочтёт ответ невнимательно

Comment: @LenovoID, например, если все клиенты локальные, то есть такой параметр в документации: --skip-networking: Do not listen for TCP/IP connections at all. All interaction with mysqld must be made using named pipes or shared memory (on Windows) or Unix socket files (on Unix). This option is highly recommended for systems where only local clients are permitted. See Section 8.12.6.2, “DNS Lookup Optimization and the Host Cache”. 

Естественно, необязательный.

Comment: @andreymal, ну, в таком смысле, согласен. Данные передаются "по нормальному" :)

Comment: Nicola я не спорил , это вам другой человек пишет - ни я